# Lazy syntax to loop through jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are some basic ways I have used to declare an jquery object while looping:

```
let $divs = $('.mydiv');

for (let i = 0; i < $divs.length; i++) {
    let $div = $($divs[i]);
}

// or

for (let $div of Array.from($divs)) {
    $div = $($div);
}

// or

Array.from($divs).forEach(function ($div) {
    $div = $($div);
});
```

I want to save the line `$div = $($div)` (for writing code faster), like these:

```
for (let $($div) of Array.from($divs)) {
    // ...
}

// or

Array.from($divs).forEach(function ($div = $($div)) {
    // ...
});
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

**UPDATE:**

Because `$('.mydiv')` can return more than 1 element, so I need a loop to work with them. But using a loop, it doesn't return an jquery object for per element, I have to wrap it by `$(...)`

Comment: Why do you not use `jQuery()` without `for` loops and reference element by index? What is issue with using `let $divs = $('.mydiv');`? Not certain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 Because I can get more than 1 object when refering `$('.mydiv')`

Comment: Yes, you can use `.eq()` to reference specific jQuery object, or `[]` to get `DOM` element by index. Or use `.filter()` to get specific element by selector, index or other unique attributes. Is "writing code faster" consistent with calling `jQuery()` multiple times? What is actual issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @foo, after you have an array of `$`-wrapped items what do you want to do with it ?

Comment: @foo _"$('.mydiv') can return more than 1 element, so I need a loop to work with them."_ What do you mean by "work with them"?

Comment: The question should be: How to cache jQuery objects from selected elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not really an answer to not really a question**

After you have an array of `$`-wrapped elements, what do you plan on doing with it?

```js
$('.mydiv')                        // = $-wrapped html collection
  .map((_, e) => $(e))             // = array of $-wrapped elements
  .each((_, e) => console.log(e))  // = log each $-wrapped element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv">1</div>
<div class="mydiv">2</div>
<div class="mydiv">3</div>
```

That's really no different than this script below, so what's the point?

```js
$('.mydiv')                          // = $-wrapped html collection
  .each((_, e) => console.log($(e))) // = log each $-wrapped element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv">1</div>
<div class="mydiv">2</div>
<div class="mydiv">3</div>
```

Comment: The point is: In the first case, you return all `mydiv` to an array which is wrapped by `$(...)` for per element. In the second case, everytime you call an element, you need to wrap it by `$(...)`